# Images used in Flutter Web app is not displaying on Production

Tags: flutter

I am designing a Flutter Web App which is working fine in local environment. Both fonts as well as images are fetched from the assets folder properly. But once i release the Web App on live server, all the images, fonts, even Material icons are not fetched and the website appears bland even though the Functionality is working as expected.
I am using `flutter build web --release --web-renderer html` to generate my release build and all the assets are present in the build/web/assets folder as well.
Here is the generated release folder structure
[image: Release folder structure]

Also i have checked the console logs of my live web app and i am constantly getting the following error

```
flutter.js:362 Exception while loading service worker: Error: prepareServiceWorker took more than 4000ms to resolve. Moving on.
    at flutter.js:48:11
(anonymous) @ flutter.js:362
manifest.json:1 
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
main.dart.js:479 
       GET /FontManifest.json 403 (Forbidden)
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:479
main.dart.js:37596 Font manifest does not exist at `assets/FontManifest.json` - ignoring.
```

I tried working to look through all the answers and checked my server configuration but everything looks fine.

Comment: tried a minimal server first? my favourite is that one: https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#python-2x or https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#python-3x (depending what python version I currently have)

Comment: Actually i am on a time crunch which doesn't allow me to try something new. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Finally worked. The actual issue was with the .htaccess file